# Wordpress - How to validate the user input password with the hashed password

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, encryption

I want to make a custom login system in wordpress. Such that it asks for username & password. But it is not authenticating the user with the given password because it is different with the password stored in db (it is in hashed form).

I read the wordpress codex for validating password I found wp_check_password method. I tried to implement wp_check_password in the below code but it is not working. Is my code missing something??

The input provided by the user

> username: admin & password: pass1q@.//aa

The hashed password stored in the database

> $P$BY.HywWHy.bpgmBZzyV6RGxG/m6.3u/

Here is the code which I am using for validation

```
$password_hashed = '$P$BY.HywWHy.bpgmBZzyV6RGxG/m6.3u/';
$plain_password = 'pass1q@.//aa';

if($wp_check_password($plain_password, $password_hashed)) {
    echo "YES, Matched";
} else {
    echo "No, Wrong Password";
}
```

Can anyone plz help me with that. Thanks looking for a positive response from the developer community.

Comment: i think the `$` before `wp_check_password`has to go away...

Comment: `$wp_check_password` is a variable, not a function

Comment: Thanks for your help, with your help i figured out that the "$" symbol is causing the problem after removing the "$" symbol it is working great. Thanks alot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_password/

Remove the $ from the function call.

Also Don't forget to include the user ID

```
$user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
if ( $user && wp_check_password( $pass, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) )
   echo "That's it";
else
   echo "Nope";
```

Comment: I used the above snippet and remove the '$' symbol as well. But it is giving the error and saying 'www.mywebsite.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500'

Comment: Did you capture the user's username in the variable $username?